# QGIS degrees - meters

Tags: qgis, shapefile, buffer

I have point data in GDA2020.  shapefile *.prj file says units are meters.  when I load the data in QGIS the layer units are degrees nd the buffer tool is always degrees.  I have searched for every setting I can find yet the layer and buffer tool are always degrees.  I have exported and re-imported, restarted QGIS.  regardless of the CRS settings the map units are always degrees.  What am i missing ?

Source data came from a table containing lat/long it looks fine in tableau or even in QGIS.  I just can't buffer it because it's not meters.  Need to do a spatial select on another point feature set.  Also, data set is Australia wide

Comment: are you sure that GDA2020 is in meters? Check here: https://epsg.io/7844 . Maybe it's this one? https://epsg.io/8032

Comment: not sure of anything.  QGIS says this for GDA2020 +proj=geocent +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs.  *.prj file has GEOCCS["GDA2020",DATUM["D_Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_2020",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: noted though the epsg site says degrees.

Comment: Is probably 7843 - https://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/datum-modernisation

Comment: What is the extent of the layer, as reported in the properties metadata tab?

Comment: Extent
113.6589929995984107,-43.3147490000191340 : 159.0713069997656817,-10.5879999999833050

Comment: may have to chop all of it into utm zones and process per zone.

Comment: What does ogrinfo report?